# Yii - LIKE on conditioned Join

Tags: mysql, join, yii

Don't ask why, but I've this tables situations.

[image]

The ActiveRecord Transport, Company, TransportDetail and TransportRow are related with Yii classic strutture (BELONG_TO, HAS_MANY etc...)

Unfortunaly, Regions, Cities and Provinces can't be related automatically to TransportDetails due to conditioned join based on fromTypeId value (there is a toTypeId column to).

Unfortunally I have to search TransportRow with a free text field that have to search in LIKE the following fields:
"company.name" (easy, with yii relations) 
"region.name or city.name or province.name based on the value of column"

To reach CompanyName and generally join every releation, Im using "with" sintax

```
$criteria->with = array('transportDetail','transportDetail.transport','transportDetail.transport.company');
```

With this auto-join, to search by company.name in OR I merge base criteria with an OR criteria:

```
$criteriaORCompany = new CDbCriteria();
$criteriaORCompany->compare('company.name',$searchFilter->name,true,'OR');
$criteria->mergeWith($criteriaORCompany);
```

This work perfectly.

Now I have to extends the search.

This query is working fine but I don't know ho to reproduce it on Yii. If you add the join to the other three tables (city,province and region) and in the where condition force to use the value only if typeColumn has the right value, the search work fine:

```
[ other join ...]
LEFT OUTER JOIN regions cr on (cr.id = transportDetail.fromId)
LEFT OUTER JOIN provinces cp on (cp.id = transportDetail.fromId) 
WHERE ((cr.name LIKE '%TEST%' and toTypeId = 'REGION') 
OR (cp.name LIKE '%TEST%' and toTypeId = 'PROVINCE'))
```

I've tried to replicate this join in Yii adding manually the join but mergWith happen before relation join

```
$criteriaLIKE = new CDbCriteria;
$crt = Region::model()->tableName();
$cpt = Province::model()->tableName();
$criteriaLIKE->join .= 'LEFT OUTER JOIN '.$crt.' cr on (cr.id = transportDetail.fromId)';
$criteriaLIKE->join .= 'LEFT OUTER JOIN '.$cpt.' cp on (cp.id = transportDetail.fromId)';
$criteriaLIKE->addCondition("cr.name LIKE '%probe%' and toTypeId = 'REGION'",'OR');
$criteriaLIKE->addCondition("cp.name LIKE '%probe%' and toTypeId = 'PROVINCE'",'OR');
```

I've tried to put mergeWith after with but it doesn't work:

```
 $criteria->with = array('transportDetail','transportDetail.transport','transportDetail.transport.company');
$criteria->mergeWith($criteriaLIKE);
```

The error is simply. With regions and province joined before the others, SQL can't find the column in the ON condition because owned but a tabled joined after them.

Sorry for long post.

Any Advice?

Comment: You want advice? Fix the schema/model. Then you wouldn't have to ask this question, because you wouldn't have a problem. You probably sense the day is coming when you'll have to do it, so that day might as well be today.

Comment: I can't touch the DB or the models.

Comment: You could propose such work to your supervisor, explaining that the current DB/model is broken and further feature enhancement will be very difficult unless it's done. See [Technical debt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) for a complete description of your situation.

Comment: I know what you mean but is not a praticable way. Too much work to adapt the current system to accept the changes. The real purpose of the topic was ask how to merge manual join and relation's join in Yii framework.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a good solution. 
First of all, ->with automation will be always added after ad explicit JOIN.
So as a first step, I translated the WITH in simple JOIN and then JOINED ALL the three tables with LEFT OUTER

```
The criteria is used on transportRows ActiveRecord

$criteria->join  = " JOIN ".TransportDetail::MODEL()->tableName()." detail ON (detail.id = t.transportDetailId)";
    $criteria->join .= " JOIN ".Transport::MODEL()->tableName()." transport ON (transport.id = detail.transporttransportId)";
    $criteria->join .= " JOIN ".Company::MODEL()->tableName()." company ON (company.id = transport.companyId)";

    $criteria->join .= " LEFT JOIN ".City::model()->tableName()." cityFrom ON (cityFrom.id = detail.fromId AND detail.fromTypeId = 'CITY')";
    $criteria->join .= " LEFT JOIN ".City::model()->tableName()." cityTo ON (cityTo.id = detail.toId AND detail.toTypeId = 'CITY')";

    $criteria->join .= " LEFT JOIN ".Region::model()->tableName()." regionFrom ON (regionFrom.id = detail.fromId AND detail.fromTypeId = 'REGION')";
    $criteria->join .= " LEFT JOIN ".Region::model()->tableName()." regionTo ON (regionTo.id = detail.toId AND detail.toTypeId = 'REGION')";

    $criteria->join .= " LEFT JOIN ".Province::model()->tableName()." provinceFrom ON (provinceFrom.id = detail.fromId AND detail.fromTypeId = 'PROVINCE')";
    $criteria->join .= " LEFT JOIN ".Province::model()->tableName()." provinceTo ON (provinceTo.id = detail.toId AND detail.toTypeId = 'PROVINCE')";

    $criteria->select = "t.*, 
                         CONCAT(IFNULL(locCompanyFrom.name,''),IFNULL(regionFrom.name,''),IFNULL(provinceFrom.name,'')) as allFrom,
                         CONCAT(IFNULL(locCompanyTo.name,''),IFNULL(regionTo.name,''),IFNULL(provinceTo.name,'')) as allTo";
```

The key is the CONCAT and IFNULL on the select. 
Only ONE of the three external table will add some string because the other two join will return NULL (due to LEFT JOIN).

So if a rows as CITY, I will have "ROME+null+null" => "ROME+''+''" => "ROME"

With this I can also order a GridView using allFrom and allTo column.

The next step is create a view using this query to join directly the main table.

Bye!